# how to make sure that the forcefield does not affect particle system

Tags: particles, force-fields, system

I'm working on a project which uses forcefield for soft body, but it is also effecting my particle system. how do i make sure it does not impact the particle system.

Answer (score 5):

You have two possible options in the *Particle Properties*. It depends on if you only want to keep those particles from being affected or if you want them to be effected by force fields but not the ones for the *Soft Body* object.

Under *Particle Properties* > *Field Weights* you can reduce the influence down to 0 for specific force fields, i.e. *Turbulence* (in my image, of course it can be *Force*, *Wind* etc. whatever is there) by turning down the slider or entering a value in the respective field. (Note: There is a slider for "All" below "Gravity", this way you can turn of all field weights except for gravity, therefore it is placed below that).

But if for example you have a *Turbulence* with settings for the *Particles*, but another one with different settings for the *Soft Body*, then simply turning down the value to 0 would result in no effect on the *Particles* at all, not even from the desired force field.

This is where the *Effector Collection* comes in handy. Let's say you have a collection with force fields for the *Soft Body* called "softbodies" and another collection with force fields for the *Particles*, maybe called "particles".

Then you choose the "particles" collection in the *Effector Collection*. Force fields that are supposed to affect both, *Soft Body* and *Particles*, don't have to be duplicated, you can assign a force field to both collections. The same works the other way around for the *Soft Body* as well, you can limit it to an *Effector Collection* there, too - to make sure some "particles" force field doesn't affect the *Soft Body*.

[image: particles field weights]

Comment: thanks a lot ::)))

Comment: @user127752 You're welcome, please read here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Just set the force value to zero.

[image]

Comment: thank you, you guys are awesome.

Comment: You are welcome