# how to make particles not to be effected by any kind of force field

Tags: particles, force-fields

I need a way to make a specified mesh or particles of a mesh not to be effected by any kind of force fields. But i need the particles to be effected by velocity at the same time
any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230612/how-to-make-sure-that-the-forcefield-does-not-affect-particle-system#230614

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @moonboots that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man :)